# Want to download Power-center express edition of informatica for free.

Tags: informatica-powercenter

> i am not able to find any link to download the power center 9.6 for informatica
>    and i want to know other requirements for installation of powercenter and is 
>   their any need for Creating a Compute Engine in Google Cloud

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Sounds like a great question for Informatica. But this isn't a programming question. Off-topic for StackOverflow.

Answer (score -1):

Current Informatica version is 10.1.1 and Informatica is not any more providing power center Express editions offline.. Only cloud version of Powercenter express is available since 10.1.1.